# Domain mapping in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

My open cart site is (http://www.example.com/). & i have created the new site in magento. & Moved all data of opencart into magento using  cartmigration extension.

My question is that how to map (http://www.example.com/) in magento if magento is install in other server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just point your domain A record to new magento server. If open cart and Magento installation are on same server then you can skip this step.
Once you have pointed domain to correct folder / server then go to Magento Database and go to "core_config_data" and change secure and unsecure links to "http://nikhilsmagicshop.com/" and if you want to run with www then change it to "http://www.nikhilsmagicshop.com/". Do not forget to have / in end.

[image]

Comment: but after doing this, it will redirect to my opencart site,

Comment: There are 2 things. You will also have to point your domain to magento root folder. Then after that you'll change URLs in Magento

Comment: if if worked, do mark it as correct :)

Comment: don't know what happen to my magento site, it will redirect to opencart again which is on other server.

Comment: Should i remove the domain record from old server where opencart is host

Comment: 1) I checked your website. It is hosted on justhost.com
2) nikhilsmagicshop.com is pointed to ns1.justhost.com and ns2.justhost.com
3) If your Magento website is in Just host, then you’ll have to change setting in just host and host nikhilsmagicshop.com in magento folder
4) If magento is on new server, then you’ll have to change DNS record to new magento server.
5) Once done, then change SQL records. You can call me up if you need help.